WPF ListBox ContentControl Animation Works Only Once Except for the Last Item

I'm working on a custom navigation bar using a ListBox in WPF. When I select an item in the ListBox, it renders content in a ContentControl. I want to apply animations to the ContentControl when its content is updated based on the selected ListBoxItem.
I have successfully added animations using DataTrigger.EnterActions, and the animation works the first time I select each ListBoxItem. However, the animation only works repeatedly for the last ListBoxItem. For the other items, the animation runs only the first time they are selected.
Here’s a simplified version of my XAML:

  <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="action_page">
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource textBlockText}" Text="ACTION PAGE" />
        </Grid>

        <!-- Other Pages Data Template -->
    
        <Storyboard x:Key="ActionPageEnterAnimation" x:Name="actionPageEnter">
            <DoubleAnimation
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                From="0.0"
                To="1.0"
                Duration="0:0:0.5" />
        </Storyboard>
    
    </DataTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>

    <Grid Margin="30">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid
            Grid.Row="0"
            Width="600"
            Height="30"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <navi:NaviListBox x:Name="bar">
                <ListBoxItem Content="ACTION" />
                <ListBoxItem Content="ENTRY" />
                <ListBoxItem Content="ALARMS" />
                <ListBoxItem Content="WARNINGS" />
            </navi:NaviListBox>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <ContentControl x:Name="contentControl">
                <ContentControl.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <!--  ACTION PAGE  -->
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedIndex, ElementName=bar}" Value="0">
                                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource action_page}" />
                                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ActionPageEnterAnimation}" />
                                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <!--  ENTRY PAGE  -->
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedIndex, ElementName=bar}" Value="1">
                                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource entry_page}" />
                                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ActionPageEnterAnimation}" />
                                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <!--  ALARMS PAGE  -->
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedIndex, ElementName=bar}" Value="2">
                                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource alarms_page}" />
                                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ActionPageEnterAnimation}" />
                                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <!--  WARNINGS PAGE  -->
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedIndex, ElementName=bar}" Value="3">
                                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource warnings_page}" />
                                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ActionPageEnterAnimation}" />
                                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ContentControl.Style>
            </ContentControl>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>


Try using x:Shared="false" for resource.

Your XAML does not compile.

It might help to add...
<DataTrigger.ExitActions>
  <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ActionPageExitAnimation}" />
</DataTrigger.ExitActions>

.... to your trigger that could look like this:
<Storyboard x:Key="ActionPageExitAnimation">
            <DoubleAnimation
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                From="1.0"
                To="0.0"
                Duration="0:0:0.5" />
        </Storyboard>

